# Use php and wamp to Insert into mdb file that opened by another program

Tags: php, ms-access, wamp

I still need to solve this issue :(

Iam running a program name QMS on Windows XP to print ticket for patient. It use Access as database. I realize that in this database there is a table name rData. When someone need to print a ticket, it will insert a new row into this table, and the column Ticketno will be plus one.
[image]

You can see in the picture above it inserted a new row with Ticketno = 258 and printer print a ticket 258 for patient.

Next, Iam install Wamp on this computer and use php to insert into this table when I want. Here is my code to insert:

```
$dbName = "E:\\2.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
try {
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 Ticketno FROM rdata WHERE ServiceId = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch();
$num = $row['Ticketno']+1;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rdata(ServiceID, Ticketno, TicketFlag, TicketChain) VALUES(1,".$num.",0,';01')";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
}
```

After I run this code, I open the file via Microsoft Access and look at table rData, I see a new row is inserted (Ticketno = 259 in this case). And I press print button with hope that it will print a ticket with number = 260.

**But**, it still print a ticket 259, and insert into rData a row with Ticketno = 259, now I have 2 rows with Ticketno = 259. It seems like the program ignore my query.

I deleted this 2 rows and do again. However, before press print button, I quit the program and reopen. Now it print ticket 260. Can someone explain this to me? What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried explicitly closing the PDO connection immediately after performing the INSERT?

Comment: @Dunn Yes, I think the previous question is not clear enough so I ask here with more detail :)

Comment: @Thompson how I can do this? Maybe $db.close() ?

Comment: Try `$db = null;`

Comment: @Thompson I tried, no luck :(

Comment: Your description of the problem is conflicted. At first you say 'inserted row 258 and printed 258'. Then later you say you 'insert 259 and hope it prints 260' Why would you expect it to print a number greater than what is entered? Please clear this up for us.

Comment: @Dunn Hi, sorry for my English. I said "IT" inserted, not "I (or me)" inserted. "IT" = the program name QMS. When you press the "physic printer button", it will insert 258 into database and print number 258 onto paper. And I want when I insert 259 into this mdb file by-php-code, and press "physic print button" again, it should print 260 as next instead of 259.

Comment: QMS inserted #258 and the printer printed #258. Is that the correct 'desired behavior' or not? I certainly hope it is because if it is NOT then you should have stated that scenario is an issue. Next, your PHP code selects 'Top 1', which should be 258, adds 1 to get to 259 and stores that in the database. Now you hope it will print #260? Why 260? How was 260 supposed to get in the database? If you enter 259 and expect 260 to print, then I hope you meant 'IT entered 258, printed 258, but I wanted 259'.  See the difference?

Comment: I adds 1 to get to 259 means I want to take the place of  259, print 259 or not is depend on me. QMS should understand that 259 was inserted (or printed) so next will be 260.

Comment: Assuming 'TicketNo' is supposed to be unique, you have a database design flaw if it allows duplicate tickets - and your code is incorrect if it attempts to store an already existing number. Where is your 'Print' code? Are you refreshing? And you still have not answered my prior comment regarding what ticket is 'entered' versus 'printed'.

Comment: I understand the database is not good. But the database is own of QMS, and QMS is not mine, I bought this system from a company :'( I have just upload an image, hope you clear. 'Print' code is unneccesary, I can connect this with a printer and print ticket later. I need the insert code work first.

Comment: How can anyone help you if you refuse to answer the questions we need to ask??? (1) Answer my question that starts 'QMS inserted #258..' (2) Why do I ask about print code? Because if your PHP code is correctly inserting the 'NEXT' record (who knows what that is because you didn't answer #1), but the print is using the wrong record, your problem lies BETWEEN the code you posted to add and the code to PRINT. Your statement above sounds like "I took a picture of a nickle, but I want to print a picture of a dime" -- and I just don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for your emthusiasm. I didn't answer your question because I know you didn't catch my problem. I don't want to insert 259 but print 260, I don't need to print, just insert is enough. Print code is not mine, it is own of QMS - a program written by someone. I want when I insert 259 into database, the QMS will think "well, I inserted 258 before, but now someone inserted 259, so I should inserted 260 as next number". I think the problem is come from QMS that I don't know it's code or how it works

Comment: Well, I can understand that if you have two separate applications (QMS and PHP) where both can add records to the same table, that things can get out of whack. In the scenario where QMS opens a recordset and sees 258 as the highest number, then someone uses PHP to insert 259, if QMS never refreshes it's recordset, it will never know 259 exists - and vice-versa. That's why apps need to be designed to handle multi-user adds and changes. So, is it possible this is your issue?

Comment: Exactly! And I don't know how to solve it. Iam not sure it is a QMS problem or this is the way how microsoft access work. I hope there is a way to modify this mdb file to solve. If not, Iam thinking how to press the "physical print button" when I need to print by code not by hand.

Comment: Since you control the Access application, you can force the new record to be +1. However, that doesn't help is someone uses QMS to add/print. Maybe contact QMS vendor, explain situation and ask what they suggest. You may need to change procedures so that after a ticket is printed, QMS must be closed...